# How to get value from telerik grid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

we use several way to get the value from Telerik grid.

[image]

but  can not get the value.

[image]

```
if (Item.Selected) {
    string id = Item["PRNO"].Text; 
    string sump = Item("ColumnUniqueName").Controls(0); 
    string Value = (Item["PRNO"].Controls[0] as Textbox).Text; 
    string firstName = (item["PRNO"].FindControl("PRNO") as Textbox).Text; 
}
```

[image]

like using this way getting value nbsp

Comment: Please show us your `telerik grid` and please do not post code as image.

Comment: attached here telerik grid
if (Item .Selected)
  { string id = Item["PRNO"].Text;
   string sump = Item("ColumnUniqueName").Controls(0);
   string Value = (Item["PRNO"].Controls[0] as Textbox).Text;
   string firstName = (item["PRNO"].FindControl("PRNO") as Textbox).Text;
  }